# Can I make CNC Editor with HTML5?

Tags: html, forms, cnc

I would like to make my own CNC Editor. 
I am looking for some guidance. I don’t know if it is even possible with HTML5. But it would be great if I can. If possible, please list what I should research and learn.

I don’t need it to be online accessible, I will only have it on my computer. I will be accessing it via local network from multiple different computers. I don’t want it accessing the internet, because it’s not always available.

Desired Features:
    ⁃   Read and Write files with different extensions (all files used are easily opened in notepad)
    ⁃   Store and retrieve data from a simple database file.
    ⁃   Make calculations 
    ⁃   Have a text Editor window 
    ⁃   Have a Display area for simple vector graphics depending on data loaded and provided by user.

Comment: Why is HTML5 a requirement?

Comment: If you add "and JavaScript", then yes, I would assume. If [Atom](https://atom.io/) can be made, then so can a CNC editor. Any more detailed answer than that would make the question off-topic, IMO.

Comment: It is a common thing on all computers, they all have chrome. Also, I know basic HTML already and I heard HTML5 is exceptionally powerful. And eventually I would like to add vector animations and stuff that I have seen online.

Comment: If I were to do it another way what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but requires a lot of work. I would say that these are technologies you would need to master in order to pull this off:

- Node.js (use express.js) - for storing and retrieving files from database and for reading/writing local files with extensions you want (server-side)
- Vue.js or Angular.js or React - for building frontend interface to manipulate your vector graphics. It can also do calculations and It's good with svgs and that kind of stuff.
- Electron.js (not mandatory) - it wraps it in native-app like experience. This framework actually gives you ability to write desktop apps for any os and arch.

So as I said, It would be a lot of work but its possible in the end.
Funny coincidence is that my brother is planning to build CNC machine so I might be doing this as well in next couple of months. Feel free to contact me if you need any further help!

UPDATE: You cant do it with just HTML5. It would be like trying to make wooden space shuttle.

Comment: Cool. Yeah, CNC machines are pretty amazing. Thanks for the info, I will start researching those items. It does look like quite an investment. But I guess for what I need, I can start out making a basic version and then build on it.  By the way, I like the wooden shuttle analogy.  Thanks again for your help.